# Angular Typescript send optional restful url params only if they are not empty

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, typescript, parameter-passing

Current system that I have control of is only the front end which is Angular 5 ( thus Typescript)  .  Backend should not matter, but there is a team in which they are not changing their signatures, their error handling etc..  :/

Issue is that there is a search screen in which only 1 field is required, so when I am trying to send a URL to a Restful backend ( actually as I type this.. this is not really restful, is it? )

**My Angular Service method:**

```
getSearchByUserResults(first,last,user,eff,term,emp) {

       //IF I JUST DO THIS, THEN EMPTY PARAMS ARE SENT AND SOMEHOW THE BACKEND IS NOT SET UP TO HANDLE THAT  :/ 
       //var params = "userid=" + user + "&first-name=" + first + "&last-name=" + last + "&eff-date=" + eff + "&term-date=" + term + "&employee-id=" + emp;

    //Sending only userid works
    //var params = "userid=" + user;

    // Send user and first when first name is empty(null) again it does NOT work
    var params = "userid=" + user + "&first-name=" + first;



    var searchUser = this._searchByUser + params;


    return this._http.get(searchUser).map((response: Response) => response.json()).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

> Basically what I am showing is in the comments above.

If a param is empty or null, then I DO NOT want it to be added to the list of params send to the server controller method...

1. if user = 123  send  http://server.com:9080//rest/config/users?userid=123
2. if user and first name not empty send  http://server.com:9080//rest/config/users?userid=123&first-name=Ted
3. Never send something with empty params like this empty first-name   http://server.com:9080//rest/config/users?userid=123&first-name=

Based on that list of params, how can I do this without a bunch of if statements checking for null/empty/undefined  ?

`first,last,user,eff,term,emp`

Comment: From your code it looks like your still using the old `Http` package instead of `HttpClient`, so I would suggest switching that out. Once you've done that, you can use the `HttpParams` object: https://angular.io/guide/http#url-parameters

Comment: Sure, but isn't there some example with old Http ?

Comment: Yes, but you'd be using a bit of code that has been deprecated since 4.3 and will be removed in future versions of Angular

Comment: Can you show me an example of this for an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, I had misread the docs, and `HttpParams` will not automatically remove null values.

You can, however, make use of an array function for this:

```
getParams(first,last,user,eff,term,emp): HttpParams {
    let obj = {first, last, user, eff, term, emp};
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((params, key) => 
            obj[key] ? params.append(key, obj[key]) : params, new HttpParams())
}
```

This will build up an `HttpParams` object that only includes truthy values, so it will exclude `null` / `undefined` / empty strings etc.

Bear in mind that `false` and `0` are also falsey values-- I'm not sure if this will be an issue in your use case.

Comment: cool that worked!   So the only thing I actually had to change in order to preserve the proper parameters was to change the let statement to this:   `let obj = {'first-name':first, 'last-name': last, 'userid':user,'eff-date': eff,'term-date': term,'employee-id': emp};`